# Trying to understand itoa function

Tags: c, do-loops, itoa

I tried to re-write the `itoa()` function from K&R exercises, but I failed to define it. I see the answer of the function in the library , but I can't understand what is inside the do block. Please explain it to me. Thanks!

```
 /* itoa:  convert n to characters in s */
 void itoa(int n, char s[])
 {
     int i, sign;

     if ((sign = n) < 0)  /* record sign */
         n = -n;          /* make n positive */
     i = 0;
     do {       /* generate digits in reverse order */
         s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';   /* get next digit */
     } while ((n /= 10) > 0);     /* delete it */
     if (sign < 0)
         s[i++] = '-';
     s[i] = '\0';
     reverse(s);
 }
```

Comment: btw, there is a nasty corner case with this itoa implementation - you cannot negate `INT_MIN` on a 2's complement machine!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';` Means:

1. `s[i++]` means char number `i` in char array `s` and increment `i` by 1
2. `n % 10` means that you take only the last digit, for example in `123`, `123 % 10` returns `3` which is a digit, this is done to **cut your number into digits** so you can create a char with each of them.
3. `+ '0'` means that you add the ascii value of the char `'0'`, for example the `int 1 + '0'` returns the character `'1'` so you can get a char array.
4. `n /= 10` means that **we remove the last digit**, indeed, we added it to our char array so we can remove it, for example `123 / 10 = 12` then you can do `12 % 10` to get the second digit: 2

This gives us a char array inverted, for example for 123 we got an array like {'3', '2', '1'} so at the end we call reverse s to (thx captain obvious) reverse our char array

For a negative `n` you can just add a `'-'` to your char array and multiply your `n` by `-1` so it become positive and you can do your job as always :)

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 3):

For a non-negative `n`:

`n /= 10` removes the least significant digit from an integral type. It's shorthand for `n = n / 10`, and any remainder from `n / 10` is discarded.

`n % 10` extracts the least significant digit from `n`, and adding that to `'0'` gives you the textural equivalent of that number. (Note this idiomatic technique works for any character *encoding* supported by C.)